# Road topology problem solution for junction

Tags: arcgis-10.0, network, topology

I am working with a Road Network. I have digitized the lines with AutoCAD Map 3D. Then Imported it to ArcMap. After entering all kind of database I have created Routing Dataset.  Unfortunately it's not giving the desired route.

The most probable problem may be the junction. I think there are few problems with junction between the road. It's a huge database and it can't be checked manually for every junction. Is there any way to create a network topology to check the junctions easily whether the roads snapped or not?

Comment: What format (AutoCAD) did you digitise in? - What format is the ArcMAP Topology in?

Comment: I have done DWG files. I have created Road Network dataset. I didn't create Network topology. This is my question, how to create a network topology.

Comment: You require the Network Analysis Extension http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/networkanalyst - Geometrics is a simplified version http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002r00000001000000

Answer (score 2):

Probably far too late for the OP but are you sure it's junction snapping that caused the problem, or is it junction intersections?  All lines must be broken at junctions if Arc is to see them as connected.

Once you're clear on what to fix, the Topology tools in ArcGIS can do this - though you need an intermediate/advanced license for them.  If you don't have that, then `v.clean` in the GRASS tools in QGIS can do it.  I made some notes on this [in the sDNA manual](http://www.cf.ac.uk/sdna/wp-content/downloads/documentation/manual/sDNA_manual_v3_0_alpha0/network_preparation.html#tools).

The (free) prepare tool that comes as part of [sDNA](http://www.cardiff.ac.uk/sdna) can also check and fix junction snapping - I added it as tolerance of link endpoints is a common problem due to the way ArcGIS handles tolerance.  Also discussed on the manual page linked above.